# How to get a simple render-context?

Tags: haskell

I'm searching for a simple render-context / canvas / video-output, with simple functions for printing pixels per pixel, per line or per image and mouse&keyboard-input. Probably without big external libs (sdl, gtk/cairo). Its fine, if it works without gpu.

Actually, i looking at xlib and xlib-bindings, but i hope there is something more abstract around and maybe with support for windows.

Comment: Isn't SDL sort of the canonical, no-frills answer to "what's a platform independent way to draw graphics primitives and handle mouse/keyboard?" Is it really too big an external library?

Comment: SDL isn't that big, but its interface is a bit ugly. Sure, xlib's interface is ugly too, but its small and installed on nearly every linux system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure wether it is exactly what you are asking, but I have found [Gloss](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) to be an excellent, no frills, 2D graphics library for quickly getting something on the screen.

Edit: Making me fight for it, are you? I like it!

A render-context is very much an imperative notion, where one manipulates the render-context by setting state on it, passing it around... Global, unseen state is generally avoided in FP, so functional programmers look for alternatives.

Gloss is such an alternative. It shuns the notion of a rendering context entirely, and uses a notion of models: Any (interactive) simulation is a process that, starting with a given state, takes a number of steps, and ends up in a different state.

What Gloss needs is this initial state, a function to 'take one step', a function to express the state as a composition of images, shapes, lines, text etc. It then does the grunt-work for us: Steps the state at regular inervals, visualizing it between each step, polling for input (another function you need to supply) in between.

I believe it uses OpenGL underneath - which only goes to underline my point: I don't need to *how* what is underneath works, it's on a lower level of abstraction.